# How to avoid duplicate insertion in MongoDB using c# without using "_id" key?

Tags: c#, mongodb, c#-10.0

I have a data like say of 5 fields in a document and suppose these 3 fields these 3 fields uniquely help identify a document.

```
Name:A, Type: B, Contact: C
```

I want to avoid duplicate entry(Insertion) in the document for these fields. I am using below code for now

```
_mongoCollection.GetCollection<ModelClass>('collectionName').Find(s => s.Name==A && s.Type==B && s.Contact==C).FirstORDefault();
```

And if this comes out to be null; we insert using :

```
_mongoCollection.getCollection<BsonDocument>('collectionName');
```

and then insert Using InsertOne. Is there a better way to implement this and avoid duplicacy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an Upsert for this:

```
var coll = _mongoCollection.getCollection<ModelClass>("collectionName");
var model = new ModelClass() 
{
  Name = A, 
  Type = B, 
  Contact = C, 
  Field4 = "F4", 
  Field5 = "F5",
};
await coll.ReplaceOneAsync(s => s.Name == model.Name 
  && s.Type == model.Type 
  && s.Contact == model.Contact, 
  model, 
  new ReplaceOptions() { IsUpsert = true });
```

The above code checks if a matching document exists; if it does, it is replaced, otherwise a new document is inserted. You could also use [`ReplaceOne`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.16/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_ReplaceOne__1_3.htm) if your method is not `async` or [`UpdateOne(Async)`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.16/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_UpdateOne__1_1.htm) for a more fine-grained update of an existing document.

### Upsert with update

For instance, if you want to only insert a new document if there is no document yet, you can use the following upsert that does not replace the document:

```
var coll = _mongoCollection.getCollection<ModelClass>("collectionName");
var model = new ModelClass() 
{
  Name = A, 
  Type = B, 
  Contact = C, 
  Field4 = "F4", 
  Field5 = "F5",
};
var update = Builders<ModelClass>.Update
  .SetOnInsert(x => x.Field4, model.Field4)
  .SetOnInsert(x => x.Field5, model.Field5);
var result = await coll.UpdateOneAsync(
  x => x.Name == model.Name && x.Type == model.Type && x.Contact == model.Contact, 
  update, 
  new UpdateOptions() { IsUpsert = true });
```

The above code creates a new document if none exists yet. If a document is inserted, you can check `result.UpsertedId`. If this is null, no document has been inserted, otherwise it contains the id of the inserted document.

The update uses only `SetOnInsert` operations for the two remaining fields. If the document already exists, it remains unchanged.

### Bulk upsert with update

If you want to perform multiple upserts with a bulk operation, you can use the following code:

```
var update = Builders<ModelClass>.Update
    .SetOnInsert(x => x.Field4, model.Field4)
    .SetOnInsert(x => x.Field5, model.Field5);
var bldr = Builders<ModelClass>.Filter;
var updates = new List<WriteModel<ModelClass>>();
var updateOneModel = new UpdateOneModel<ModelClass>(
    bldr.Eq(x => x.Name, model.Name) & bldr.Eq(x => x.Type, model.Type) & bldr.Eq(x => x.Contact, model.Contact), 
    update);
updateOneModel.IsUpsert = true;
updates.Add(updateOneModel);
// ... add additional UpdateModels
var result = await coll.BulkWriteAsync(updates);
```

In this case, result contains a list of upserted ids; there also is an `Index` property that you can use to find out which `UpdateModels` have led to an upsert and which haven't.

Comment: thanks for the answer. However I don't want to replace the existing record. However, just check whether record is there or not, if not, it inserts and if present , it gives a message that "duplicate record present".  As of now, I am using below command                                           `ModelClass mc= _mongoConnection.GetCollection<ModelClass>("collectionname").Find(s => s.Name == model.Name 
  && s.Type == model.Type 
  && s.Contact == model.Contact).FirstOrDefault();`      to check if record present in Db n then insert them.

Comment: The problem is I have to check this for multiple records, when data is more. For example this model is actuall a List<Model> So I ahve applied a forLoop on it , and checking it one by one

Comment: @Krypto456 I've added some more sample code both for updates without replace and for bulk updates

Comment: thanks a lot! However I do have query My method is not Async , so i removed "await" . But now when I check (result.Upserted == null) {some code}, it give error on 'Upserted' as 'Task<UpdatedResult> doesnot contain a definition for 'UpsertedId' and no accessible method 'UpsertedId' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<Updateresult> could be found. Could this be my method is `public Task<ResponseModel> Insertdata ()`

Comment: @Krypto456 usually there is a synchronous version also; if you remove the `await`, remove the `Async` from the method name also. You might have to tweak the parameters a bit also, if there are differences between the async and the synchronous version.